Metrics of constant Gauss curvature on 2-cylinder
Let $C=S^1\times[0,1]$ be a compact cylinder. Given positive numbers $l,\lambda>0$. Is it possible to construct a smooth Riemannian metric on $C$ of constant Gauss curvature -1 such that one connected component of the boundary $\partial C$ will be geodesic, while the second one will have length $l$ and constant geodesic curvature (second fundamental form) $\lambda$?

This reduces to an initial value problem for an ODE. Have you tried to write that down?

@DeaneYang: How do you get ODE (rather than PDE)?

In order to define sign of the curvature of a boundary curve, you have to specify the normal direction. Do you want the 2nd boundary component to be convex or concave?

Assume the metric is rotationally symmetric

Did you realize that the accepted answer is incomplete and does not work if $|\lambda|\ge 1$?

An equidistant curve to a line in hyperbolic plane has constant geodesic curvature. So pick a line $L$ in $\mathbb H^2$ and pick $r>0$ such that the $r$-equidistant curves have the desired geodesic curvature. Let $L_r$ be one of them. After this pick a translation $f: \mathbb H^2 \rightarrow \mathbb H^2$ along $L$ such that the quotient of $L_r$ by $f$ has length $l$. The quotient by $f$ of the strip bounded by $L$ and $L_r$ produces the desired cylinder.

Keep in mind that the geodesic curvature of your $L_r$ (sometimes  called a hypercycle) is between $0$ and $1$ (or $-1$ depending on your orientation convention), this is a nice exercise in differential geometry. Thus, if $|\lambda|\ge 1$ you will never reach the "desired" curvature.
